# How a DBA can monitor multiple huge SQL Server databases more than 2 tera bytes

Tags: sql-server

I need a some suggestions from you people, I am not a DBA but moving to DBA platform.

I have some questions/clarifications can any body answer? Please.

1. We have almost 350 servers and more than 2500 database how can we monitor all those in a shot(interms is one DBA can handle or multiple DBA are there in a shift).
2. How can we monitor all those databases backups and performance.
3. If per Client individual how many production server will be there.
4. As an average a DBA how many databases can handle.
5. How will we provide security for Database?

Can any one answer these questions please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Lots of questions so many answers. It depends on so many factors. Budget being one.

First of all I would like to point out that visiting some basic SQL Server courses will vastly increase your understanding of SQL Server and its requirements. IMHO switching from Windows Server Administrator to SQL Server DBA is not just something that can be accomplished by querying Google or asking questions in a forum. You can acquire some knowledge, but without the full picture, you are liable to break something in a productive environment.

1. Do a search for SQL Server Monitoring Tools in Google. You should get a list of well known products back.
2. That depends on the monitoring software you purchase. Some can handle these requirements some not. There are also freeware tools available that could help with certain aspects.
3. Some monitoring products can handle up to 200-250 servers per instance depending on the load and the frequency of polling.
4. Brent Ozar has an article on this aspect: [How many servers can one person manage?](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/12/how-many-servers-can-one-person-manage/), and then again: it depends.
5. So many aspects here:

   - Don't hand out the **sa** password! **Never**!
   - Windows Server admins are not DBAs and should not have access to the SQL Server instance. (My opinion)
   - People outside of the Server or DBA team should not have access to backup drives or to SQL Server database file locations.
   - Only a qualified **DBA** should be allowed to be have **sysadmin** server role
   - Limit each SQL Login/NT Login to the least possible number of databases.
   - Limit the SQL Login to different roles depending on usage

     - DB_NAME_User : db_datareader, db_datawriter
     - DB_NAME_Dbo : db_owner
   - Try [Transparent Database Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049.aspx)
   - Try [Database Backup Encryption](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489.aspx)

Security depends on the requirements of your business. Ask the head of IT for SLAs or OLAs and any company-wide security policies, etc.

One question you haven't yet asked is: Availability. Will you be required to have [Always on Availability Groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff877884.aspx)?

You asked a lot of questions, I hope you have a general starting point.

Answer (score 1):

> We have almost 350 servers and more than 2500 database how can we monitor all those in a shot

That's what I look after. You need either a lot of money to spend on specialist monitoring software (it will be in the high 5 or low 6 figures), or someone who is really awesome with PowerShell.

> How can we monitor all those databases backups and performance.

At that scale and with limited staff (3 full time DBAs) the name of the game is standardisation and operational validation (that servers meet your standards). Typically that begins with rolling out a standard for backups, integrity, and index maintenance. After that there's security.

Performance is the last thing you'd care about - when it's on that scale you won't have time to care. Typically you'd license a specialist tool for a handful of licenses and deploy it temporarily between specific troublesome instances as required.

> If per Client individual how many production server will be there.

25-100%. It doesn't matter. For operational validation you will want to treat every server the same; the only change is the order in which you roll those changes out.

> As an average a DBA how many databases can handle.

Depends. But without one super advanced senior used to working at scale, plus two more for an on call roster, you're hosed.

> How will we provide security for Database?

When you take something like this over you let management know the risks. Backups, maintenance, and security in that order. You can't work on systems until you know you've got backups to roll back to so that takes priority. There is breathing room before you could really get into trouble for past security failures.

But once you have that stuff down the next steps will be patching, and rolling out login traces and gathering data to a central repository. This gives you the information you need to start making decisions on what is and is not safe to lock down. Disabling SA accounts is the priority but as they're often used you can't just do it until you've identified they're not used or had people make configuration changes on their applications. After that then comes sysadmin but not-sa accounts, and of course privileges at a Windows level. But that's a good year or two down the line.

Answer (score -1):

As @hot2use said, this is a huge topic. I'm not going to answer but instead make a suggestion. Monitoring several databases such as you describe is a full time job, and this is what I'm doing currently in my firm. So again, I'm not answering (and hope not to be reward with bad points) but making a suggestion. That is, maybe you would be interested in a live monitoring solution that we can provide. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

Alerts are raised on customized thresholds on backup, uptime, users, high availability etc.